# libusb bulk transfer lose packets

Tags: c++, c, libusb

I need to retrieve data from a controller that emit a kind of stream of data through an USB port.

I am trying to retrieve such data with libusb synchronous bulk transfer.
We can get up to 164 000 000 bytes of data.

Datas are emited in several "chunk / batch" of data.
For example, let's say the controller emit a block of data one by one.

What I do is something near to :

```
bool finished = false;
unsigned char *data = malloc(maxSize);

while(!finished) {
     int transferSize = 0;
     int result = libusb_bulk_transfer(handle,
                                       LIBUSB_ENDPOINT_IN  | 1,
                                       data + alreadyRead,
                                       32768,
                                       &transferSize, 1000);
     // if we finish to read
     if(alreadyRead > 0 && result == LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT)
         finished = true;
     alreadyRead += transferSize;
}
```

When the CPU is idle, everything works fine. However, when the cpu is used (lot of other thread that are running), I lose some chunk. It is like when between the end of one `libusb_bulk_transfer` and the beginning of the same function, some chunks are already sent and have vanished.

Is there a way to "bufferize" the bulk transfer?
Does asynchronous transfer may solve the problem?
Thanks !

Comment: Did you remove the error-handling to keep your posted code size down?

Comment: Yes. But I do not get any other error than TIMEOUT

Comment: Well, ok, what happens if you set 10000 timeout?

Comment: Nothing more. When he finish to read a chunk (and I think it reads it in some milliseconds) it returns 0 not taking account the timeout since all data are considered read...